# How do I define new entity in Spacy nlp

Tags: python, spacy

I want to define a new entity in Spacy.

My code needs to achieve the following:

- search text for a certain keyword (here: "Streitwert")
- if keyword is in text find sentence where the word occurs
- in that sentence look for the number
- this number should be an entity with a label "keyword"

This is my code but it is not working:

```
def get_keyword_value(token):
    if "Streitwert" in token.doc.text: 
        for sent in token.doc.sents:
            if "Streitwert" in sent.text:
                for token in sent:
                    if token.pos_ == "NUM":
                        return token.text


import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Token
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
Token.set_extension("Streitwert", getter=get_keyword_value, force=True)

text = "Die ist ein langer Text. Der Streitwert wird auf EUR 12.000 EUR festgesetzt"
doc = nlp(text)

[(token.text, token._.Streitwert) for token in doc]
```

The code is not working properly and has two issues

1. every token has the token._.Streitwert = 12.000 (but it should only be the token 12.000
2. how do I define a new doc.ents with a label "Streitwert"

What I actually want is that the "12.000" is labelled as "Streitwert" when I do

`[(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents]`

Answer (score 0):

As for defining a new custom entity, you can easily add to the list of entities: `ents`. To find out how you can do this, I recommend look at this relatively short SpaCy example that is doing something very similar to what you want to do:
https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#on_match

In this example, they match a word and, based on the match, they add a custom entity. Here they use the ORTH property, but you can use {"POS": "NUM"} to suit your needs. Also, you might find it helpful to use the [Rule-based Matcher Explorer](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=120%20kilograms%20of%20dagga%20seized%20from%20Cape%20Town%20shacks.&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22NUM%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22kilograms%2C%20kg%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22of%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22DEP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22pobj%22%7D%5D%7D%5D) to play around with your matterns in a nice friendly UI. In this example, there's no need to set a custom attribute.

If, however, you choose to go the custom attribute route, then you're right that you need to use Token.set_extension(...) to enable the token level custom property. I'd imagine you want to set the default to `False` and then overwrite that `False` with `True` if the token is "Streitwert". You can do that by adding a the default parameter.

```
Token.set_extension("Streitwert", default=None, force=True)
```

Also, I notice that your get_key_word(...) method doesn't return anything most of the time. i.e. If any of the conditions are `False`, what value should be returned?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I set the default to `False`. I tried to include as a parameter in the set_extension function. But it is not possible to set a getter function and a default value. I will have a look into the documentation. I do struggle to fully understand it, though. But thanks for your hints!

Comment: I see what you mean about not being able to set the default value and the get function. I really think that will be best to look at that SpaCy example. They are doing almost the same thing as you but their approach is known to work.